# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, Update 2, I'm getting a `This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect.` if I do the following:

1. Hit `F5` to start the site, see my site in Chrome
2. Press the red Stop icon in Visual Studio
3. Go back to Chrome and hit `F5` to Refresh, see the error

How can I leave the IIS open so it continues to serve my localhost? Before installing the Update 2, this would work. I even have the following *unchecked*: `Enable Edit and Continue` in Tools -> Options -> Debugging. Having this unchecked used to allow me to hit the red Stop icon and still be able to see my site in the browser.

Comment: You could start without debugging `Cntrl + F5`. It would let the IIS Express run in the background.

Comment: `Start Without Debugging` (**`Ctrl+F5`**) keeps running your site unless and until you quit **`IIS`**.

Answer (score 1):

In update 2 you can use "Detach All" to detach visual studio from the debugger and still leave IIS express running.  This has the same effect at "Stop" did prior to update 2.

To add "Detach All" to your menu

- Click the drop down arrow on the debug tool bar and select "Add or Remove buttons"
  [image]
- On the menu click "Customize..."
  [image]
- Then click "Add Command..."
  [image]
- Choose the "Debug" Category
- Scroll down to "Detach All" and click OK
  [image]
- OK out of all the menus and off you go.